# Data not updating when API changed on Vue Js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-component

Ok, I have a problem, here I make a data post with a tag, and when I click the tag the other data posts are not updated by the tag.

i'm get the api with created function, Do I have to use vuex?

can everyone help me, thanks very much

this is my template

```
<div class="col-md-4 mb-4" v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
                        <div class="card h-100 shadow-sm border-0 rounded-lg">
                            <div class="card-img">
                                <img :src="path+'/storage/posts/'+post.image" class="w-100"
                                    style="height: 200px;object-fit: cover;border-top-left-radius: .3rem;border-top-right-radius: .3rem;">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <router-link :to="{name: 'detail_post', params: {slug: post.slug}}"
                                    class="text-dark text-decoration-none">
                                    <h6>{{ post.title }}</h6>
                                </router-link>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer bg-white">
                                <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ post.created_at }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

this is my JavaScript

```
<script>
    //import axios
    import axios from 'axios'

    export default {
        name: 'PostIndex',
        data() {
            return {
                path: axios.defaults.baseURL,
                posts: []
            }
        },
        created() {
            //get post homepage
            axios.get(`/api/tag/${this.$route.params.slug}`).then(response => {
                this.posts = response.data.data.data;
            })

        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure about the response content of the `GET` call? Also you should install https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools it's a chrome addon allowing you to debug your VueJS applications

Comment: i have already devtools bro

Comment: And what does it say about the content of `posts`?

Comment: when i click the other tag, data post not re-rendering, i check on the devtools

Comment: Replace the axios call by that `setTimeout(() => { this.posts = [{id:1,title:'1',slug:'1'},{id:2,title:'2',slug:'2'}]; }, 2000);` if it works after 2s then the problem is with your API data

Comment: thanks very much, but sam the problem bro

Comment: I tried this: https://pastebin.com/z5fttps4 and it works so I guess your problem is elsewhere :/ can't help you much more

Comment: yeh worked on the first request, but when i click other link tag, data still not get update